# I can't add a spinner in my fragment java code

Tags: android-studio, fragment

i'm a beginner in android studio and i need help with adding a spinner into my fragment. I understand that it isn't the same as adding it into an activity. However i have tried various methods that seemed to have work out for others but myself.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_input_barrel, container, false);

    String [] values=
            {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7",};
    Spinner spinner= getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return getView();
```

The string values that i have added has an error and i can't understand why. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the View first , and call the corresponding spinner from the view and set the adapter and then return the View.
Change your code as below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manual, container, false);


    String [] values=
            {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7",};
    Spinner spinner= v.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
```

Hope this helps...